# Spring MVC cyrillic global variables injected as unreadable symbols

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cyrillic

How to set and get cyrillic global variable with @Value annotation in Spring MVC?

The property file encoding is utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution

```
<bean id="globalProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="location" value="classpath:global.properties"/>
            <property name="fileEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

> ```
>     @Autowired
>       @Qualifier("globalProperties")
>       private FactoryBean<Properties> arlmVersions;
> ```